# Is there a jQuery function for converting time zones?

Tags: jquery, algorithm, datetime, timezone

For my needs, I care mainly about the continental U.S. (Pacific, Mountain, Central, and Eastern time zones), but a bonus would include the others, too.

What I wonder is if there is a known jQuery function that will return values that take into consideration daylight saving time when converting from one hour to anothertaking daylight saving time rules into account.

I reckon it would be called something like this:

```
var pertinentDatetime = getDateTimeFor(thisDateTime, thisTimeZone, desiredTimeZone);
```

Does anybody have or know of such a function?

Comment: No. Apart from [`$.now()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) jQuery doesn't come with anything concerning time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, jQuery does not have built-in support for dealing time information like time zones.

Check out [Moment](http://momentjs.com/).

The following should give what you want:

```
moment().zone();
```

Comment: I have played around with it, but I have heard from many friends that it is a very useful library. I have worked Date.js quite a bit and love it.

Comment: I checked it out and they have a timezone component all to itself.  var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();